# Is there a way to make popup messages in Flame/Flutter without using widgets?

Tags: flutter, popup, flame

I want to add popup messages to my Flame/Flutter game, but I'm having a hard time finding how to do that.  I want a popup window that says "You need to open the door" at the beginning of a level (or whatever the message is for that level, it will change).  I then want them to select ok and have the message disappear.  I don't want anything else to be able to work until they select ok.

Is there a way to do this without creating a widget or some sort of button/text box that has to stay on the screen all the time?

I've been looking up how to do popup boxes, but they only seem to be with widgets.  The only think I can think of to fix the problem is to create a permanent text box and button combo, but I would rather some form of popup, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways that you can do this, if you don't want to use widgets you could create a component that contains a `TextComponent` or `TextBoxComponent` and a `ButtonComponent`. Then you can either add that component directly to the component tree, or you can use the [RouterComponent](https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/router.html) and add a route for the popup.

With the `RouterComponent` you can also easily add `OverlayRoute`s, if you later decide that you want to build this popup with Flutter widgets.